# sliding window for K nearest links search on an adjacent list represented road map

Tags: algorithm, graph, gis, knn, sliding-window

I am doing a K nearest links search on a road network, which is represented by an adjacency list (e.g. `adj[1] = {{3,0.5},{8,0.6},{9,1.0}} means node1 is connected to node 3, 8, 9 and the links have the weights of 0.5, 0.6, 1.0 respectively.`). I want to use a sliding window so when searching for a point, instead of parsing the whole graph, I can use the sliding window to get a local neighboorhood to search inside. 
However, I really don't know how to get this window(or more precisely the links inside this window).

PS:
the data structure I used for adjacency list in C++:

```
struct neighbor{
    int id; 
    double weight;
};

typedef map<int, vector<neighbor> > adjacency_list;
```

Comment: Please try and explain again what this sliding window means and what you expect of it. Also, is the list of adjacent nodes ordered in some way?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov I just edited the question, sorry about the confusions. the sliding windows is something that can help me extract the neighbooring links or nodes of a particular point, so we don't need to parse the whole graph to search for its knn. The adjacency list is not sorted(because I used a struct neighbor{int id; double weight;} data structure) and then the adjacency list is map<int, vector<neighbor> >